# Create El Capitan install partition

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I went through a lot of articles on how to create bootable os x install partition but eventually I ended up with a need of making resize of my system partition - unfortunately DiskUtility shows this option greyed out. Any ideas why? I don't want to loose my existing system installation.

[image: DiskUtility window screenshot]

Properties say that it is a physical volume and it's not using CoreStorage.
This is the output of diskutil list command:

[image: diskutil list]

And it seems like I managed to resize this disk0s2 partition with:

```
diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 480GB
```

command. Still don't get why this option is absent in DiskUtility. It used to be there. And unfortunately this is not what I was looking for. After I resized this volume DiskUtility didn't allow me to create a new partition. Therefore I think the problem is in that I didn't partition drive properly from the very beginning. diskutil splitPartition doesn't work at all - it says that it cannot unmount disk. Any ideas other than to wipe HDD contents out and install from scratch? I don't want to install Snow Leopard first and update it to El Capitan.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return everything back:

```
diskutil resizevolume disk0s2 R
```

and then:

```
diskutil resizeVolume disk0s2 480G jhfsx InstallOSX 10G
```

> Resizing a volume that is currently set as the computer’s startup disk
>   will invalidate that setting; use the Startup Disk System
>   Preferences panel or bless (8) to reset the resized volume as the
>   startup disk.

Comment: I will try it this evening when I get to home.

Comment: I removed the `1`! The resizeVolume (in contrary to the splitPartition) verb doesn't require a *numberofPartitions*.

Comment: Yes, this command works fine. I managed to extract InstallESD.dmg to this partition, but it doesn't seem that it is bootable. How can I make it bootable?

Comment: @cave-canem I have chosen recover from image to extract InstallESD to this partition. It's of hfs+ type now. But it is not bootable.

Comment: I do not quite understand what it means to "make a bootable InstallESD"

Comment: @cave-canem I tried to burn InstallESD.dmg manually. I think that the article that I followed is a bit errant. I managed to locate https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201372 and I think I will try it this evening.